# addClass and removeClass in jQuery - not removing class

Tags: jquery, dom, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I'm trying to do something very simple. Basically I have a clickable div 'hot spot', when you click that it fills the screen and displays some content. I achieved this by simply changing the class of div, removing 'spot' and adding 'grown' and there's a little CSS animation to make it grow. This works fine.

The problem is, within this div there is a close_button, which at the moment is just text. I want this to switch the classes back - i.e. remove grown and readd spot. It doesn't do this when clicked. I believe it's to do with the element not having those classes when the DOM loads, but I'm new to jQuery and don't know how to work around this.

I think there's probably a much more sensible way of doing it, could someone point me in the right direction? I'd be very grateful. I've tried using toggleClass instead to no avail.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {      
    $(".clickable").click(function() {  
        $(this).addClass("grown");  
        $(this).removeClass("spot");
    });   

    $(".close_button").click(function() {  
        alert (this);
        $("#spot1").removeClass("grown");  
        $("#spot1").addClass("spot");
    });   
});
```

UPDATE:

I am using this code now,

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $(document).on("click", ".close_button", function () { 
        alert ("oi");
        $("#spot1").addClass("spot");
        $("#spot1").removeClass("grown");
    });  


    $(document).on("click", ".clickable", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("spot")){
            $(this).addClass("grown");
            $(this).removeClass("spot");
        }
    });
});
```

strangely the close_button function still won't add 'spot' or remove 'grown' though it will add any other classes and it will remove other classes... I added the if clause because I thought perhaps both function were being triggered at the same time, undoing each other, but it seems to make no difference

Comment: Can you show us your html? With this code, you add and remove class on the .close_button element.

Comment: <div class="clickable spot" id="spot1">
            <div class="white"></div>
   <article class="purple" id="story1">
                <div>
                    <p class="date">posted 20 Jan 14</p>
                    <p class="region">Bangladesh</p>
                    <p class="title">Story Title</p>
                    <p>Egestas eros ac risus faucibusr</p>
                    <a class="close_button">CLOSE</a>
                </div>
            </article>
            </div>

Comment: I'm seeing an identical property. When I swap my version of "$(this).removeClass("spot");" for "$(this).removeAttr("class");" it removes all classes except for spot - infuriating.

Comment: Is there another function somewhere that adds or assigns the class to those elements or a range of elements in which they are included?

Answer (score 84):

What happens is that your close button is placed inside your `.clickable` div, so the click event will be triggered in both elements.

The event bubbling will make the click event propagate from the child nodes to their parents. So your `.close_button` callback will be executed first, and when `.clickable` is reached, it will toggle the classes again. As this run very fast you can't notice the two events happened.

```
                    / \
--------------------| |-----------------
| .clickable        | |                |
|   ----------------| |-----------     |
|   | .close_button | |          |     |
|   ------------------------------     |
|             event bubbling           |
----------------------------------------
```

To prevent your event from reaching `.clickable`, you need to add the event parameter to your callback function and then call the `stopPropagation` method on it.

```
$(".close_button").click(function (e) { 
    $("#spot1").addClass("spot");
    $("#spot1").removeClass("grown");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u4GCk/1/

More info about event order in general: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html (that's where I picked that pretty ASCII art =])

Comment: Just for completion, there are actually several ways you can prevent events bubbling up, each with its own subtleties. For example, `return false` not only stops propagation but also stops the default action. See this [article for further reference](http://markupjavascript.blogspot.in/2013/10/event-bubbling-how-to-prevent-it.html).

Answer (score 16):

The issue is caused because of [event bubbling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4616720/297641). The first part of your code to add `.grown` works fine.

The second part "removing grown class" on clicking the link doesn't work as expected as both the handler for `.close_button` and `.clickable` are executed. So it removes and readd the `grown` class to the `div`.

You can avoid this by using `e.stopPropagation()` inside `.close_button` click handler to avoid the event from bubbling.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/vL8DP/

**Full Code**

```
$(document).on('click', '.clickable', function () {
   $(this).addClass('grown').removeClass('spot');
}).on('click', '.close_button', function (e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).closest('.clickable').removeClass('grown').addClass('spot');
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Whenever I see `addClass` and `removeClass` I think why not just use `toggleClass`. In this case we can remove the `.clickable` class to avoid event bubbling, and to avoid the event from being fired on everything we click inside of the `.clickable` `div`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".close_button", function () { 
    $(this).closest(".grown").toggleClass("spot grown clickable");
});  

$(document).on("click", ".clickable", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("spot grown clickable");
});
```

I also recommend a parent wrapper for your `.clickable` `divs` instead of using the `document`. I am not sure how you are adding them dynamically so didn't want to assume your layout for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/bplumb/ECQg5/2/

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 7):

I would recomend to cache the jQuery objects you use more than once.
For Instance:

```
    $(document).on("click", ".clickable", function () {
        $(this).addClass("grown");
        $(this).removeClass("spot");
    });
```

would be:

```
    var doc = $(document);
    doc.on('click', '.clickable', function(){
       var currentClickedObject = $(this);
       currentClickedObject.addClass('grown');
       currentClickedObject.removeClass('spot');
    });
```

its actually more code, BUT it is muuuuuuch faster because you dont have to "walk" through the whole jQuery library in order to get the $(this) object.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're almost there. 
The thing is, your `$(this)` in the "close button" listener is not the clickable div. So you want to search it first. try to replace `$(this)` with `$(this).closest(".clickable")` . And don't forget the `e.stopPropagation()` as Guilherme is suggesting. that should be something like:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {   
    $(document).on("click", ".close_button", function () { 
        alert ("oi");
        e.stopPropagation()
        $(this).closest(".clickable").addClass("spot");
        $(this).closest(".clickable").removeClass("grown");
    });  


    $(document).on("click", ".clickable", function () {
        if ($(this).hasClass("spot")){
            $(this).addClass("grown");
            $(this).removeClass("spot");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

you need event delegation as these classes are not present on DOM when DOM is ready.

```
$(document).on("click", ".clickable", function () {
    $(this).addClass("grown");
    $(this).removeClass("spot");
});
$(document).on("click", ".close_button", function () {  
    $("#spot1").removeClass("grown");
    $("#spot1").addClass("spot");
});
```

Comment: I had tried this before and really thought it would solve the problem, but it does nothing... I put an alert in to confirm the click is working on the close button, the div id is definitely correct (spot1)...

Comment: I've also noticed - I can add classes other than 'spot' fine, just not 'spot'! I then thought perhaps the first function was being called at the same time as the second and they were cancelling each other out, so I added:

$(document).on("click", ".clickable", function () {
   if ($(this).hasClass("spot")){
       
    $(this).addClass("grown");
    $(this).removeClass("spot");
   }

});

$(document).on("click", ".close_button", function () { 
    alert ("oi");
    $("#spot1").addClass("spot");
    $("#spot1").removeClass("grown");
});  

...to no avail

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('.close-button').on('click', function(){
  $('.element').removeClass('grown');
  $('.element').addClass('spot');
});

$('.element').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeClass('spot');
  $(this).addClass('grown');
});
```

I hope I understood your question.

Answer (score 1):

**why not simplify it?**

jquery

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {//on parent click
    $(this).removeClass('spot').addClass('grown');//use remove/add Class here because it needs to perform the same action every time, you don't want a toggle
}).children('.close_button').on('click', function(e) {//on close click
    e.stopPropagation();//stops click from triggering on parent
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('spot grown');//since this only appears when .grown is present, toggling will work great instead of add/remove Class and save some space
});
```

This way it's much easier to maintain.

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/3SmaV/

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the nesting of the elements. Once you attach an event to the outer element the clicks on the inner elements are actually firing the same click event for the outer element. So, you actually never go to the second state. What you can do is to check the clicked element. And if it is the close button then to avoid the class changing. Here is my solution:

```
var element = $(".clickable");
var closeButton = element.find(".close_button");
var onElementClick = function(e) {
    if(e.target !== closeButton[0]) {
        element.removeClass("spot").addClass("grown");
        element.off("click");
        closeButton.on("click", onCloseClick);
    }
}
var onCloseClick = function() {
    element.removeClass("grown").addClass("spot");
    closeButton.off("click");
    element.on("click", onElementClick);
}
element.on("click", onElementClick);
```

In addition I'm adding and removing event handlers.

JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/zmw9E/1/

Answer (score 0):

I actually just resolved an issue I was having by swapping around the order that I was altering the properties in. For example I was changing the attribute first but I actually had to remove the class and add the new class before modifying the attributes. I'm not sure why it worked but it did. So something to try would be to change from `$("XXXX").attr('something').removeClass( "class" ).addClass( "newClass" )` to `$("XXXX").removeClass( "class" ).addClass( "newClass" ).attr('something')`.