# Bootstrap hidden class

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem using Bootstrap and Wordpress admin panel.

Basically, I have some Bower components installed, and when I build my project, they all get concatenated together (for both CSS and JS).

The problem is: Bootstrap `.hidden` class uses `!important`

This is an issue for me as some elements on wordpress admin side look like this:

```
... class=".... hidden" style="display:none" ...>
```

They have both class .hidden and inline style.

Wordpress default `.hidden` class gets replaced by Bootstrap class, and so the inline style gets ignored as well as Bootsrap's`!important` prevent it to change from `display: none` to `display: block`.

Unfortunately, I need bootstrap on the backend for a lot of other stuff.

Is there any way I can replace that class? (i just want to get rid of `!important` keeping everything else the same)

Ideally, without changing bootstrap core `css` so that it's update-safe

ps: Will this be different on Bootstrap 4? I don't mind updating it if it solves this issue.

Thanks

Comment: they replace `.hidden` class from twitter-bootstrap-4 with `.hidden-xs-up` ([link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/19254)).

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look into bootstrap 4 then

Comment: I tried using the new bootstrap4 alpha, but it's still there and still not working...any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end i decided to use http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ and just create a theme that includes what i needed bootstrap for.

This way i can include a specific strip down version of bootstrap with only buttons and icons (which is what i needed on backend anyways) without having issues with class conflicts anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `$('the_CSS_Type_Selector').removeClass('TheClassToRemove')`.
and you can change attributes using `.attr()`

Ref- 1. [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18986623/addclass-and-removeclass-in-jquery-not-removing-class)
2. [jQuery .removeClass](http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this means I have to search for eahc instance of that class in the whole admin section of wordpress. I was hoping for something a bit more generic to be honest

Comment: The inheritance and priority in CSS may also help you to come out. The more specific selector in CSS the more effective it is. Like `html {color: blue !important}` is overcome by `html.no-js{color: red !important}`

Comment: If you could paste the situations (HTML code and the CSS on inspect element), then I can tell you specifically the way to select and overcome...

Comment: Yes, I know that. Unfortunately I have various stuff to change the CSS, and using this method it's not an option as elements are variable and may even be a lot (also hundred s)

Comment: Try using `div.hidden{display: block !important}` as this is more specific than `.hidden` class

Comment: And I would not suggest you to edit any core file. Better target with you code so that at any time you know the problem.

Comment: Then try editing the core file but makke sure that they do not affect other things...

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the !important from the bootstrap css.

If you dont have the files loacally on your machine you have to download them though.

Comment: I use bower to install it, meaning that everytime I download bootstrap I need to apply the same change again and that's not really update-safe